# How can I reset my ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, finder, mdm

I have an Ipad that has find my phone on it and I cannot reset it.  The person who owned it is not alive anymore to ask the proper questions

Comment: They sold you an iPad, and then died? Do you at least have documentation to prove that you have bought it from them?

Comment: It was given to a son and he brought it to me to try and get it working

Comment: It is possible to do via Apple support, maybe if you called them, explained what was going on they could tell you the requirements. These are likely (at least) a death certificate, and likely more.

Answer (score 2):

Apple's documentation for deleting, or accessing, someone's AppleID can be found here:

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/102431

> If you’d like to request the permanent deletion of an Apple ID and
> data for someone who has passed away, you’ll need your Apple ID, the
> Apple ID for the account you want to delete and the required legal
> documentation for your country or region. You can start a request to
> delete a deceased person’s Apple ID on the Digital Legacy – Delete
> Apple ID page. https://digital-legacy.apple.com